# Identify the screen is locked in WindlowsPhone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In my application I need to know when device is locked. How to detect when the screen is locked, also when unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public App()  
{  
RootFrame.Obscured += Obscured;    
RootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Obscured/Unobscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) events.
But there are some limitations:

- it rases [not only when](http://codecise.com/blog/wp7-messagebox-raising-obscured-event) you are under the lock screen.

> This event is raised when the lock
>   screen is engaged **or when some other action obscures** the running
>   application’s frame, such as an incoming phone call.

- there is a delay. You got the Obscured event after screen locks. So, if you try to check the state and navigate to other page, your app may be killed by OS.